# Transform scale: problem with scaling down

Tags: css, animation, transform, scale

I am facing to some kind of weird [problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bGH0k.png), which occurs after scaling down the element.

[image]

```css
div{
  padding: 60px;
  margin:100px;
  background-color:red;
  transition:1s;
}
div:hover {
  transform:scale(1.2);
}
```

```html
<div>abc</div>
```

Have you ever met with something like this? Does it occur because of some performance issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Ah, i hoped that it will be clear from the image which i also posted. As element is scaling down i get stuck weird lines (in the image u can see them). I dont want it there, i would like to get exactly same state which was before scaling up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a 3D transformation instead:

```css
div{
  padding: 60px;
  margin:100px;
  background-color:red;
  transition:1s;
  transform:perspective(100px) translateZ(0);
}
div:hover {
  transform:perspective(100px) translateZ(10px);
}
```

```html
<div>abc</div>
```